# Particle motion with discrete values for the potential

Tags: differential-equations, physics

Sorry if the question seems trivial, but I am new to physical simulations in Mathematica. I have a numerical estimation of an electric potential $V(x)$ in 3D, to be more precise I have a matrix containing $[x , y, z , V(x, y, z)]$ in a cubic domain, so the potential in not an analytic function . Is there a method, using Mathematica, to solve numerically the equation of motion for a charged particle in the potential? Essentially I would like to solve $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \textbf{x}(t) = e \nabla V (\textbf{x}(t)) $ with certain initial conditions.

Comment: Is your discrete function a sampling or approximation of an underlying continuous function?  If so, use `FindFit` to get the 3D potential and then `Solve` to calculate the particle trajectories.  (If instead your potential is constant within a cubelet, then the derivatives vanish and if your particle ever sits within a cubelet, it will remain in that cubelet forever, even though regions with lower potential may exist.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: No, the discrete function is the result of a finite element simulation. An analytic model for the potential doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Please take a look at `Interpolation[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
(*Your matrix*)
max = 2 Pi; 
pot = Table[{{x, y, z}, Sin@x y z } // N, {x, 0, max, max/40}, {y, 0, max,  max/20}, 
                                          {z, 0, max, max/20}];
v = Interpolation@Flatten[pot, 2];
dx[x_, y_, z_] := D[v[r, y, z], r] /. r -> x
dy[x_, y_, z_] := D[v[x, r, z], r] /. r -> y
dz[x_, y_, z_] := D[v[x, y, r], r] /. r -> z

sol = NDSolve[{
    x''[t] == dx[x[t], y[t], z[t]], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1,
    y''[t] == dy[x[t], y[t], z[t]], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1,
    z''[t] == dz[x[t], y[t], z[t]], z[0] == 1, z'[0] == 0
    },
   {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 2}];

ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your solution seems to work correctly. The only issue is related to the mesh of the sampling that in my case is not uniform and gives a warning. The solution is computed though.

Comment: @user47224 If you search this site you'll find a couple of questions about interpolating in non-uniform grids. Thanks for the accept!